# Select specified weekdays in ASP calender control

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I have this calender in my webpage and i want that user choose only the weekdays that i specify in my code behind and the rest of the days are disabled( for example user could only choose Monday,Tuesday and Thursday of the weeks).
I should use this method but i don't know how can i do that, if someone could help?

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`CalendarDay.IsSelectable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendarday.isselectable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [`IsWeekEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendarday.isweekend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    e.Day.IsSelectable = !e.Day.IsWeekend;
}
```

**Edit**: i thought that you only want weekdays, if you want to specify the days:

```
private DayOfWeek[] AllowedDays = { DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Thursday };

protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    e.Day.IsSelectable = AllowedDays.Contains(e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek);
}
```

Comment: What about the days that are not weekend for example Monday or Tuesday ?

Comment: @Colt: sorry, i've misunderstood the question. Give me some time.

Comment: Thanks for giving your time

Comment: @Colt: i have edited my answer, you can use a collection as lookup.